# Converting a column to date format (DDMMMyyyy) in pyspark.I am getting whole column(date) as null

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

While changing the format of column week_end_date from string to date, I am getting whole column as null.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp, from_unixtime
df = spark.read.csv('dbfs:/location/abc.txt', 
header=True)

df2 = df.select(
'week_end_date', 
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('week_end_date', 'MM-dd-yyyy')).alias('date')
).show()

print(df2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format is incorrect. It should be `ddMMMyy`. You can also directly use `to_date` instead of unix timestamp functions.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.read.csv('dbfs:/location/abc.txt', header=True)

df2 = df.select(
    'week_end_date', 
    F.to_date('week_end_date', 'ddMMMyy').alias('date')
)
```

If you want the format to be transformed to `MM-dd-yyyy`, you can use `date_format`:

```
df2 = df.select(
    'week_end_date', 
    F.date_format(F.to_date('week_end_date', 'ddMMMyy'), 'MM-dd-yyyy').alias('date')
)
```